# Indigo Maven Project Builder

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

In Eclipse it is possible to configure builders for a project.  I am using m2e and Eclipse indigo for a dynamic web project.  I am trying to figure out *exactly* what happens when I invoke Build for the project from eclipse and so be able to understand the difference between this and a just doing a maven build from the command line. I go to project / builders and see there are five builders: JavaScript Validator, Java Builder, Faceted Project Validation Builder, Maven Prokect Builer and Validation.  It would be interesting to see what goals the Maven Project Builder will do  but I can't see this from this screen.  Edit is disabled.  I try Project Properties / Maven and there is nothing to do with Goals there.  Even though this http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Preventing-Maven-project-builder-from-being-run-td137622.html suggests there should be.

I am wondering is there any way to see and configure what goals Eclipse will call?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Strange as it sounds, m2e does not really invoke Maven to do the build.

Its job is to parse POM file and delegate the job of doing everything that it finds there to Eclipse.

It does so by mapping maven plugins to special m2e Eclipse plugins.

Sometimes, when no mapping exists you get a warning and you have a choice of either disabling this part of your build or running the maven plugin in I guess default wrapper provided by m2e.  In either case the result is not as good as when a maven-to-eclipse plugin mapping exists

Comment: Thanks. If I disable all builders except the Maven Project Builder nothing gets built. This would suggest that the "compile" goal is being skipped.  It would be interesting to know what else the Maven Project Builder skips?

Comment: +1 for explaining this. So, `m2e` does not require the Maven package to be installed? i.e. no calls to `mvn` are made when `m2e` is used? Please clarify.

Comment: @Daniel. You don't need external mvn installation with Eclipse (although it will help if you want to run command-line builds).  However, m2e has support for console maven builds (available through `Run As` context menu of Maven project), and for this it needs maven installation.  By default it embeds blessed installation into Eclipse, but you have an option to override it through `Global Preferences->Maven->Installation` dialog.